# Python ram write and read

Tags: python, python-3.x, ram

I want to do someting like this with python on linux. For example , a.py create a list and write it memory , and b.py or c.py read it from memory by  which is writed by a.py .
I dont want to use text files.

I dont know,  is there posibble or not .

Thanks for answers.

Comment: Maybe you can use import.

Comment: If you want to run several python processes and share data between them, you can try to use in-memory key-value db like `redis`

Comment: I think redis is good for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) to run `a.py and b.py` and build a memory mapped pipe between them to pass native python objects like lists, dicts.

Example, Suppose we want to receive something in a.py from b.py:

In a.py:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
import b

if __name__ == '__main__':
    recv_end, send_end = Pipe()
    p = Process(target=b.sender_func, args=(send_end,))
    p.start()
    print(recv_end.recv())   # prints "Please accept my greetings!"
```

In b.py:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe

def sender_func(send_end):
    msg = "Please accept my greetings!"
    send_end.send(msg)
    send_end.close()
```